# Display Main menu only on login page

Tags: routes

I am using **Webform module** and I used main menu to display the form on `Login page`. I want to display menu only on `Login page` but `Main menu` is also displaying on `front page`. Is their any way to hide displaying `main menu` on `front page`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 simple options (And even more with preprocessors, but I won't go into that):

1. Most themes auto output the primary and secondary menu (configured in Appearance -> Global/THEMENAME -> Settings). You can turn it off on the theme settings, and use the Block system (Structure -> Blocks -> Main menu -> Configure) to put it on the pages (2 valid urls):

   ```
   /user
   /user/login
   ```

   pages only.
2. (This is exactly the same as 1 except it's not database configuration, it's a code edit) Edit the `page.tpl.php` and comment out the lines that go something like:

   ```
   if($primary_menu) { print $primary_menu; }
   ```

   and again use the block system to output the main menu block on the login page (2 valid urls - see 1)
3. Or alternatively you can create a new custom menu, stick your form link there, and use the block system to assign it to the login page (2 valid urls - see 1). And leave your Main menu empty.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 use **Block Visibility settings** to control the block Visibility.

Use PHP code:

[image]

```
    <?php
        if(/* Your conditon */){
            return TRUE
        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Except if the theme displays the main menu outside of a block, as is sometimes the case.